# Rails with Hotwire/Turbo doing get requests on link hover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

Using rails (7.1.3.2) and turbo-rails (2.0.4). For some reason, when ever I hover over any link in my app, a GET request is happening to the linked page. I check my inspector and there is a mouseenter event coming from `turbo.es2017-esm.js:3135`.

When I disable it, the GET requests don't happen.

Here is an example of a link I have

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "hover:text-black flex-none", data: { turbo_frame: :resource_frame } %>
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a new instaclick behavior in *Turbo v8*:
*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/1101*

You can disable it by adding a meta tag to your page:

```html
<meta name="turbo-prefetch" content="false">
```

or data attribute to/around your links:

```html
<a href="/" data-turbo-prefetch="false">Home</a>

<div data-turbo-prefetch="false">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  ...
</div>
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#prefetching-links-on-hover*