Why is flask-turbo following links on hover?
I'm at complete loss.  In this minimal turbo_flask application when I hover over the link "run test", it follows the link without me clicking on it.  I did not implement any javascript to do this.  Can someone tell me what is going on?
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from turbo_flask import Turbo

app = Flask(__name__)
turbo = Turbo(app)

data = {
}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('start.html', data=data)

@app.route('/wtf')
def wtf():
    turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template('wtf.html', data=data), target='workspace'))
    return {}


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=10004, debug=True, use_reloader=False)

start.html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

    <title>TRTS</title>

    {{ turbo() }}
  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <div class="container-xxl text-light">
      <turbo-frame id="workspace">
        <h3 class="fw-bold mb-0 fs-4 text-body-emphasis"><a href="/wtf">Run Test</a></h3>
      </turbo-frame>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

wtf.html
<h1>WTF?!</h1>


there is a preloading behavior enabled by default https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043099/207090
